# When should I use preprocessor directives over if statements

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, I am learning C, and I was wondering: when should I prioritize this syntax, for example

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define ALIVE 1

int main(void) {
    #if ALIVE
    printf("Alive");
    #else
    printf("Unalived");
    #endif
}
```

Over this syntax (example):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define ALIVE 1

int main(void) {
    if (ALIVE)
        printf("Alive");
    else
        printf("Unalived");
}
```

Thank you for spending time reading my question, I hope this isn't a dumb question and I wish you a nice day.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a dumb question, though it's a fairly basic one.  However, I *would* characterize it primarily as a question of code style, hence primarily opinion-based.

Comment: It isn't opinion-based. Use `#if` for _compile time_ conditional code and `if` for _run-time_ code execution.

Comment: The second one relies on compiler optimizations to eliminate the dead code, but has the advantage of fully checking the dead code for errors. The first one only checks that the dead code consists of a sequence of pre-processing tokens.

Comment: Also, the second one will continue to work when you decide to make `ALIVE` a run-time configuration setting.

Comment: @Dúthomhas, an `if` with a constant condition is highly likely to be evaluated at compile time, and semantically, it doesn't matter whether it is evaluated at compile time or run time if indeed both are viable.

Comment: The second form is likely to spit out a compiler warning about constant in conditional expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, and to see the main difference between the two programs you show, let's see how they will look after preprocessing.

The first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ALIVE 1

int main(void) {
    #if ALIVE
    printf("Alive");
    #else
    printf("Unalived");
    #endif
}
```

will expand to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Alive");
}
```

The second one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ALIVE 1

int main(void) {
    if (ALIVE)
        printf("Alive");
    else
        printf("Unalived");
}
```

will expand to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    if (1)
        printf("Alive");
    else
        printf("Unalived");
}
```

<sub>[Examples above skip the actual inclusion of the header file]</sub>

While this doesn't directly answer your question it can give hints to what using the preprocessor conditional compilation for.

The main use is to conditionally give the compiler different code depending on the macros. Mostly used for portability-issues, when creating programs that needs to be built for different systems (for example Linux and Windows).

When using the preprocessor to do conditional compilation, whole parts of the code, that would otherwise be invalid on the target system, could simply be omitted and the compiler won't even see it.

If you use the standard C `if` statement, then both branches of the condition *must* be valid code that the compiler can build.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, you should always prefer `if (`... over `#if` and should only use `#if` where `if` will not work

- when there's something in the if that is syntactically incorrect when the condition is false so it won't compile at all
- when you need to do this at the global scope, where statements (like `if`) are not allowed

in your example, the `if` version is much better.